# Why DBIx column is not deflated?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have `InflateColumn` defined like this

```
__PACKAGE__->inflate_column( request => { inflate => sub{ die },  deflate => sub{ die } } );
```

But when I try to store data into this column it is stored without problem.

```
$schema->resultset( 'Table' )->create({
    request => 'value'
});
```

Why is `inflate/deflate` not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deflate` will be called when `value` is an array reference or a hash reference

```
$schema->resultset( 'Table' )->create({
    request => [ 'value' ]
});
```

**UPD** The [DOC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/InflateColumn.pod#DESCRIPTION)

> It will handle all types of references except scalar references. It will not handle scalar values, these are ignored and thus passed through to SQL::Abstract. This is to allow setting raw values to "just work". Scalar references are passed through to the database to deal with, to allow such settings as \'year + 1' and \'DEFAULT' to work.
>
> If you want **to filter plain scalar values and replace them with something else**, see [DBIx::Class::FilterColumn](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/FilterColumn.pod).

Comment: As the InflateColumn docs state: It will handle all types of references except scalar references.